# Input data from C# Form

Tags: c#, sql

I am having trouble updating data into a table from my C# form. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong. It does not give me an error and says that it has been submitted successfully. My database show no change however.

```
try
        {

            string cmdstring = "UPDATE Test SET COLLECTION_DATE = '@date', SPECIMANID = '@spec', TEST_RESULT = '@result', SUBSTANCE_RESULT = '@substance' WHERE PEOPLESOFT_EMPL_ID = @empID ;";
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstring, con))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@spec", OleDbType.Char).Value = textBoxSpec.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@result", OleDbType.Char).Value = comboBoxResult.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@substance", OleDbType.Char).Value = comboBoxSubstance.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empID", OleDbType.Char).Value = textBoxID.Text;



                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Submitted Successfully");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed due to " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :** You are enclosing the Parameters in your update query within single quotes.

**Solution :** while using *parameterised queries* you should not enclose the parameters within single quotes, so you need to remove the single quotes around the parameters in update query.

Try This:

```
string cmdstring = "UPDATE Test SET COLLECTION_DATE = @date, SPECIMANID = @spec, 
 TEST_RESULT = @result, SUBSTANCE_RESULT = @substance WHERE PEOPLESOFT_EMPL_ID = 
                                                                      @empID ;";
```

**Suggestion:** You are displaying the success mesaage without checking the query execution status.

i would suggest you to verify the `ExecuteNonQuery()` return value before displaying the Success message.

From MSDN :`ExecuteNonQuey()`

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and **returns
>   the number of rows affected.**

Try This:

```
int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(rowsUpdated > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Records Inserted Successfully!");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Insertion Failed!");
```